# Railsデプロイ後にローカルでDBが起動できない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

**できないこと**
自作アプリをRender.comで無事にデプロイ後、ローカルでも開発を進めようと思ったのですが、DBにアクセスできなくなってしまいました。

**エラー内容**
Rspecでテストをしようと思ったのですが、エラーが出たため試しに"rails db:reset"をしてみました。そしたら、同様に、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not translate host name "xxxxxxxxxxxx" to address: Name or service not known
```

**やりたいこと**
このエラーを解消して、きちんとローカルでも開発し続けるようにしたいです。

**懸念**
エラー文で検索したら解決策っぽい記事は出てきたのですが、デプロイした方にも何か影響がないか懸念しています。どなたかご存知であればアドバイスください。

**追加項目**
*database.yml*

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem "pg"
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: k_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user running Rails.
  #username: k

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: k_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password or a full connection URL as an environment
# variable when you boot the app. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# If the connection URL is provided in the special DATABASE_URL environment
# variable, Rails will automatically merge its configuration values on top of
# the values provided in this file. Alternatively, you can specify a connection
# URL environment variable explicitly:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV["MY_APP_DATABASE_URL"] %>
#
# Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full overview on how database connection configuration can be specified.
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: k_production
  username: <%= ENV["K_DATABASE_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["K_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Answer (score 2):

database.ymlを変更していませんか？

render.comならDATABASE_URL環境変数に接続情報を入れてると思うので、そうであれば次のような感じで、ローカルと本番同じファイルで設定を使い分けるのが一般的かと思います。

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_HOST") { "localhost" } %>
  port: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_PORT") { 5432 } %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_USERNAME") { "postgres" } %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_PASSWORD") { "password" } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_URL") { "" } %>
```

状況が分からないので、これ以上はなんとも

Comment: Yuichi T さん　コメントありがとうございます。そうですね、載せてもらっているように別ファイル上に接続情報を入れています。この場合、default の方に同様に書き加えればいいということでしょうか？本番環境のデータベースとごちゃごちゃになったりはしないものでしょうか？

Comment: 別ファイル上というのは？本番環境とごっちゃになるとしたら書き方がまずいです。ファイルの内容を貼ってくれますか。（もちろんパスワードなど直接書いているならそれは適当な文字列に置き換えて）

Comment: Yuichi Tさん　わかりづらくてすいません。今挙げますが、別ファイルで書いているというのは、直接パスワードやユーザー名は書かないで、.envに環境変数を書いてそれをdatabase.ymlで読み込んでいる感じです。

Comment: やりようはいろいろありますけど、.envに書いてあるのであれば、usernameとpasswordをdefaultに移動して、ローカル開発をするときはローカル開発用の .env を置けばよいと思いますよ。

Comment: .envはバージョン管理に含めないで、 .env.sample のようなのを作って（これは含める）、環境に合わせて .env を作るのがよくある手だと思います。

Comment: YuichiTさん　.envに書いてあるのであれば、usernameとpasswordをdefaultに移動して、ローカル開発をするときはローカル開発用の .env を置けばよいと思いますよ。→usernameとpasswordというのは最初に書いてもらった　”username: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_USERNAME") { "postgres" } %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_PASSWORD") { "password" } %>”　この部分のことでしょうか？また、このpostgres,password の部分は各々の環境で代入するなにかのことでしょうか？

Comment: YuichiTさん　.envに関してはバージョン管理には含んでいません。環境に合わせて作るというのは、開発用、デプロイ用みたいなことでしょうか？

Comment: はい。開発環境では開発環境のデータベース設定を書いた物を置き、本番環境では本番環境の設定を書いた物を置きます。このように環境によって変化する変数をリポジトリから切り離して扱うのに .env は有用です。

Comment: となると、.envの一つのファイル内に、本番環境用の設定を書いたものはあるけれど、開発環境用で書いていないからそっちでは動かなくなってしまっているわけですね。具体的に、開発環境でDBを動かすために何が必要とか、わかるようなものは何かご存知でしょうか？

Comment: 具体的にも何もさっきので答えですが…。もともと開発環境で動いていたのなら、その設定に戻せばよいのでは。

Comment: database.ymlのproductionセクションの、username: <%= ENV["K_DATABASE_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["K_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>を defaultセクションに移して、開発環境の.envには開発用データベースのユーザー名、パスワードを K_DATABASE_USERNAME K_DATABASE_PASSWORD に書けば良いです。

Comment: あとこのdatabase.yml、productionセクションのホスト名が設定されていませんけど、本当に今productionで動いているのと同じ物ですか？